# Wordpress cannot establish connection to wordpress.org

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am a newbie in WP and I got the following error:

[image]

This happens when I tried to update plugins, go to plugin page, update wordpress etc.

Why this is happening?

My php is 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for such problems, here are possible cases you can check:

1. Are you running in Localhost environment? Sometimes, when WordPress is not able to connect to wordpress.org server. It can show errors.
2. Some plugin/themes in your site in not compatible with php7, make sure all your plugins are compatible.
   You can try disabling all plugins and switching to the default theme to see if the problem still persists.
3. Downgrade to lower PHP version ( PHP 5.6 ), to see if the problem still there.
4. Try updating WordPress manually- Delete all files in your website except `wp-contents` folder and `wp-config` file.
   Get a fresh copy of deleted files from wordpress.org